# Universal Analytic Framework

Tags: logic, metaphysics, categorical-framework, analysis

I've been working on a philosophical framework called Universal Analytic Framework. This is actually a personal philosophical project. I am in the process of designing a framework that has fluidity, modularity, universality, diachronicity, adaptability, versatility,  comprehensivity as its properties. It can also work for generating novel paradigms. My question to you all is this: can there be a Universal Analytic Framework that is a sort of classic framework for the work of analysis which can be superimposed on any type of data and which will yield knowledge as the output? It is one step beyond epistemology really. When our lives are flooded with so much data and information, can there be an Universal Analytic Framework that can be applied to the structured as well as unstructured data to yield knowledge? So far, my philosophising has brought me to an answer: the interrogatives. The six interrogatives: "What is," "why is," "when is," "how is," "where is," "which is," are the six essential tools for analysis. Can there be generation of infinite interrogatives? Or can there be a classical set of interrogatives that is applicable to all data? Or are there any other alternatives than interrogatives that will fulfill the requirements of a Universal Analytic Framework?

Comment: Sorry, we do not comment on individual projects.

Comment: Universal as in the only one necessary? What if I think mine's better? Is the word universal perhaps too grandiose? Or is your system's uniqueness and supremacy an important aspect of its definition?

Comment: Universal, as in the most widely applicable, the most versatile, classic in dealing with diachronicity.

Answer (score 2):

Willard Quine, in Two Dogmas of Empiricism, demonstrated that no language has sufficient clarity of terms to support analytics.  https://www.theologie.uzh.ch/dam/jcr:ffffffff-fbd6-1538-0000-000070cf64bc/Quine51.pdf Therefore the answer to your question is no.  There cannot be a Universal Analytic Framework that can be superimposed on any type of data and which will yield knowledge as the output.

Comment: This sounds vaguely analogous to Gödel's incompleteness theorem, Turing's Halting problem, and Tarski's undefinability theorem. Any connection?

Comment: I think there is a loose commonality, as each of these were discoveries that the absolutes of logic and analytics are really not achievable in in human or worldly contexts.  The Munchausen Trilemma, and its effect on the principle of sufficient reason, falls into this family of failures for absolutes as well.